# Folder Inside ASP.NET Website Only Accessible By One User?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, active-directory

We're running **Microsoft Server 2008** using **IIS 7**. Our website is set up such that any **Active Directory** user who is a part of our *main group* can access anything (any .aspx file) within the website. Of course, if they are not using Internet Explorer, they will be prompted to enter their username and password.

One folder within the website (MVCPages folder) appears to be only accessible to one single AD user (this guy is no longer with us). We're trying to figure out why all files within this particular folder are only accessible to him. He is (1) an AD user who is a part of the same group that everyone else is and (2) the folder permissions are virtually identical to all other folders within the website.

I believe this is folder based because if you try to access any files within the folder (I haven't tried all becuase there are 50+ .aspx files) then you are rejected unless you are signed in as him.

If you have any questions feel free to ask.

Thanks

Comment: Could be something in the code itself checking on the authenticated username, or it could be permissions defined in the web.config file?

Comment: Since it's folder specific, there's a good chance that it has something to do with the file system permissions for that folder.

Comment: Matt, thanks for the response. It was in fact an issue in the web.config file. That web.config file was restricting access to all files within its enclosing folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue in the `web.config` file.

Lines...

```
<allow roles="Admins" />

<deny users="*" />
```

... caused all users without Admins role to be unable to access the page.